# What is the use of Spring's init-method and destroy-method?

Tags: spring

While learning Spring framework, I found that Spring framework provides `init-method` and `destroy-methods` which can be used to initialize some properties or to do housekeeping stuff.

We can do all those things in the bean's constructor so why do Spring provides these things and in the real world what is the actual use of these two things?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use setter-based dependency injection, the `init-method` makes it possible to perform initialization: the specified method will be called after all the setters have been called.

As per `destroy-method`, it seems that implementing `finalize` in Java classes is not a good practice, instead, and many libraries define a `close` method which may or may not be called from `finalize`. See this discussion:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158174/why-would-you-ever-implement-finalize

**EDIT** (to clarify things even further)

In setter-based injection methods will be called in the following order:

1. default constructor
2. the setters corresponding to each `<property>` of the bean
3. the `init-method`, if specified

In constructor-based injection methods will be called in the following order:

1. the matching constructor
2. the `init-method`, if specified

Comment: shoot.... I forgot about setter based injection. In this case 'init-method' is really helpful. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: In case of constructor dependency injection, is init-method performs the initialization or constructor itself does?

Comment: The constructor will be invoked first, and then the init-method (if specified). See my updated answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The argument is one that continually happens in spring/java circles. Here's a few blog posts which illuminate most of the important points:

- [Setter injection vs Constructor injection](http://blog.springsource.org/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required/)
- [Constructor injection vs Setter injection](http://misko.hevery.com/2009/02/19/constructor-injection-vs-setter-injection/)
- [Yet another Constructor injection vs Setter injection](http://alexcuesta.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/constructor-injection-vs-setter-injection/)

Primary arguments for constructor injection:

1. Constructor injection ensures all mandatory properties have been satisfied, and it is **simply not possible to instantiate an object in an invalid state**
2. Enforces the order of initialization and prevents circular dependencies

Comment: Circular dependencies is a key benefit of setter injection. From the humble back-pointer and beyond.

Answer (score 0):

For setter injection of XML configured beans, the init-method gives you the opportunity to check the state of your object before any methods get called. Remember there is no compile-time check that an argument is passed to initialize each field of the object. So even though a setter may be defined in the java class, the bean definition in the XML could be missing a property tag.